# Comparing 2 inputs with multiple rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, compare

I was trying to compare the 2 inputs (`qty` and `minStock`) in the below script. Each row has an update button. It is working in a single row, but if I have multiple rows this script won't work on the second row down to the last row.

How can I compare 2 inputs with multiple rows? Thanks in advance.

```js
$("body").delegate(".update", "click", function(event) {
  var update = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  var update_id = update.find(".update").attr("update_id");
  var qty = update.find(".qty").val();
  var available_stock = update.find(".available_stock").val();
  var minStock = update.find(".minStock").val();
  var n = $("#qty").val();
  var m = $("#minStock").val();

  if (parseInt(m) >= parseInt(n)) {
    alert("The quantity you have entered must be greater than or equal the minimum stock!");
    exit();
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "orderAction.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      updateCartItem: 1,
      update_id: update_id,
      qty: qty,
      available_stock: available_stock,
      minStock: minStock
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#cart_msg").html(data);
      checkOutDetails();
      // remove the mesages
      $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).hide(10, function() {
          $(this).remove();
        });
      }); // /.alert
    }
  })
})
```

my PHP code inside the while loop;

```
                    echo
                    '<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <a href="#" remove_id="'.$cart_item_id.'" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                                    <a href="#" update_id="'.$cart_item_id.'" class="btn btn-primary update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="" value="'.$cart_item_id.'"/>

                            <div class="col-md-2">'.$items_code.'</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">'.$items_name.'</div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control available_stock" id="available_stock" name="available_stock" value="'.$available_stock.'"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control minStock" id="minStock" name="minStock" value="'.$minStock.'"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control qty" id="qty" name="qty" value="'.$qty.'" ></div>

                        </div><br>';
```

Comment: You appear to be using repeated `id` attributes which is the cause of the problem. Select the `#qty` and `#minStock` elements by class instead. You will also need to use DOM traversal to find the related qty and minStock to the `.update`  button which was clicked. Exactly how you do that depends on your HTML.

Comment: exit() in js???. I am not sure. Use return instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks for editing my question. Anyhow, my `id` is not being repeated. I have edited my question and look at my html code inside the mysql while loop.

Comment: @ObitoUchiha, Hi, thanks for the response. I've tried using the `return;` but it is just the same.

Comment: I have solved this issue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In your posted while loop, you create `input` elements with the ids `qty`, `available_stock` and `min_stock`. When you now select the input by it's id you end up always getting the first occurance of this id in the DOM. => IDs NEED to be unique.

```
 var n = $("#qty").val();      // -> will always be the first #qty inputs' value
 var m = $("#minStock").val(); // -> will always be the first #minStock inputs' value
```

You already selected the right values with

```
var qty = update.find(".qty").val();
var minStock = update.find(".minStock").val();
var available_stock = update.find(".available_stock").val();
```

Compare these in your Condition, cause they will hold the corrosponding value for each row. This will make your ids of these input fields redundant and you can get rid of them.

```
if (parseInt(minStock) >= parseInt(qty)) {
  alert("The quantity you have entered must be greater than or equal the minimum stock!");
  exit();
}
```

Aside: if you have full controll over the HTML that is getting output, you should think about adding some classes to your html elements so that stuff like this:

```
var update = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

gets unnessecary. If you change your HTML structur - for example you remove the `.btn-group` - all your JS is invalid. You should add a class to your `.row` element that can get easily selected:

```
<div class="row myNewSelectorClass">...
```

The readability of your code will improve alot.

Comment: Thanks @Lapskaus. But, I didn't get what you mean.